# CakePHP 2.0 - Plugin Model without an underlying database table

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-model

I'm having difficulty in creating a Cake 2.0 plugin with a model that is not associated with an underlying database table.

The [Cake Manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html) says that you can set the variable *public $useTable = false;* but when I load my plugin with this in my model I still get the missing database table error message.

This is the beginning of my class definition (where my plugin is called OneTime):

```
class Ticket extends OneTimeAppModel {

/*
 * This model does not use a database table
 *
 * @var boolean
 */
public $useTable = FALSE;
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: This could be a bug. Consider asking/reporting it for the Cake2 guys. http://ask.cakephp.org/ and http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/dashboard respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a workaround in the meanwhile, I've been using this:

`public $uses = array();`